# Calling async method results in WaitingForActivation “Not yet computed” error

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm not sure why call to an async method yields no result. Below is my code, which makes call to same async function twice, however latter fails to to yield any result and results in

```
Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

Code:

```
void async void FunctiontHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var dwnldKeybankFilePrefix = prefix + "KEYBANK_" + Function.outputZipFileSuffix + "/ST";
    var dwnldKeybankListTask = toEFS.ListDownloadObjectsAsync(bucket, dwnldKeybankFilePrefix, s3client);
              
    var dwnldKeybankList = await dwnldKeybankListTask;
                   
    var dwnldAOCFilePrefix = prefix + "AOC_" + Function.outputZipFileSuffix + "/" + AOCFilePrefix;

    //Here the method yields nothing and comes up with message as stated above
    var dwnldAOCListTask = toEFS.ListDownloadObjectsAsync(bucket, dwnldAOCFilePrefix, s3client);
    var dwnldAOCList = await dwnldKeybankListTask;     
    dwnldKeybankList.AddRange(dwnldAOCList);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure this is your problem,

however, you are awaiting `await dwnldKeybankListTask` twice, and not awaiting `dwnldAOCListTask` at all and passing the task straight to `dwnldKeybankList`

Try this

```
void async void FunctiontHandler(S3Event s3Event, ILambdaContext context)
{
    var bankPrefix = $"{prefix}KEYBANK_{Function.outputZipFileSuffix}/ST";

    var bankList = await  toEFS.ListDownloadObjectsAsync(bucket, bankPrefix , s3client);

    var aocPrefix = $"{prefix}AOC_{Function.outputZipFileSuffix}/{AOCFilePrefix}";

    var aocList = await toEFS.ListDownloadObjectsAsync(bucket, aocPrefix, s3client);

    bankList.AddRange(aocList);
}
```

Also you are using `async void`, 9 times out of 10 you will actually want `async Task`. Additionally your variables names are fairly confusing

Comment: async void is used because FunctiontHandler is an event handler and it's advisable to use  async void only for even handlers. Nevertheless you spotted the problem, it was 'await dwnldKeybankListTask' Have rectified it and it now works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Aniruddha yeah it was a bit of a head scratcher there for a moment